# Exchanging out specific lines of a file

Tags: python, file, python-3.x

I don't know if this should be obvious to the more tech savvy among us but is there a specific way to read a line out of a text file, then edit it and insert it back into the file in the original location? I have looked on the site but all the solutions I find seem to be for python 2.7.

Below is an example of what I am looking for:

```
    with open example.txt as file:
           for line in file: 
                 if myline in file:
                     file.edit("foo","fah")
```

Comment: You mean you need to replace all the occurrences of `foo` with `fah`?

Comment: No just in the specific line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this by using `fileinput` with `inplace` passed. You still cannot just do a one-line edit, you much conditionally change the line you need and let everything else as is.

In short with a file looking like:

```
$ head example.txt
pass
pass
foo
pass
```

You could do:

```
import fileinput

with fileinput.input('example.txt', inplace=True) as f:
    for line in f:
        print('fah' if 'foo' in line else line.strip())
```

For a result of:

```
$ head example.txt                     
pass
pass
fah
pass
```

Answer (score 1):

In 95% cases, replacing data (e.g. text) in a file usually means

1. Read the file in chunks, e.g. line-by-line
2. Edit the chunk
3. Write the edited chunk to a new file
4. Replace the old file with a new file.

So, a simple code will be:

```
import os

with open(in_path, 'r') as fin:
    with open(temp_path, 'w') as fout:
        for line in fin:
            line.replace('foo', 'fah')
            fout.write(line)

os.rename(temp_path, in_path)
```

Why not in-place replacements? Well, a file is a fixed sequence of bytes, and the only way to grow it - is to append to the end of file. Now, if you want to replace the data of the same length - no problems. However if the original and new sequences' lengths differ - there is a trouble: a new sequence will be overwriting the following characters. E.g.

```
original: abc hello abc world
replace abc -> 12345
result: 12345ello 12345orld
```